# How should I go about dividing functionality into Java classes?

Tags: java, coding-style, refactoring, web-scraping

I'm working on a moderate-sized Java project and trying to stick to the best possible practices, so I thought I'd run a few questions by you guys. Since I currently have time, I want to do it right. My apologies in advance if this sort of question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow. Perhaps others can refer to it for stylistic advice.

I'm writing a class called LinkOpener which has one public, static method: openAgencyWindows. You feed it an (oil) well serial number and, based on the serial number, a opens regulatory website for any one of the 50 US states. I'd be doing quite a bit of scraping, and due to the labyrinthine nature of these websites the code can get pretty extensive. Should I:

1. Include all of my scraping code in a LinkOpener class, including methods to handle serial numbers that correspond to each state in the US (sorted alphabetically).
2. Give each state its own class, which would extend a Scraper class that contains a few common website scraping/regex methods. Each state class would have one to three methods to assist with scraping.
3. Do something else?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your second alternative will be more readable and a more object-oriented approach, which is good. It is also possible to call methods in the specific classes without knowing what state it is through abstract methods in the implemented class.